# how to access parent view reponder

Tags: iphone

I have 3 viewcontroller. FirsViewController, SecondViewController and ThirdViewController. The FirstviewController is root viewcontroller and it is adding secondviewcontrooler xib as the subview. like..

[firstviewcontrollerObject.view addsubview:secondViewcontrollerObj.view].

In secondViewcontroller I have one button. When button touch action is called, ThirdViewController is loaded. like..

[SecondViewControllerobj.view addsubview:thirdviewcontrollerobj.view];

Now ThirdViewCOntroller is on the screen. This viewcontroller has nothing only a small button. So I am seeing 2 buttons on screen. First button is of SecondviewCOntroller and second button is of ThirdViewCOntroller. But, I am able to give touch action of 3rdviewcontroller only not 2ndviewcontroller button.

How should I design my view to take touch of both button and I don't want to merge both controller i one.

Comment: what do you mean by access click event?

Comment: It is about button responder.

Comment: Do you want to listen to the click or trigger the action?

Comment: @balla I edited question. It may be clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should implement it without using multiple UIViewControllers.

View Controllers are useful for pushing and poping from a navigation stack: with only one view displayed at time. I did not try, but I think that's why you get the bug.

But you prefered navigationControllers to the benefits of their xib, did't you?

If so, there is a way to use xib with views :

```
NSArray * arr1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView1" owner:nil options:nil];
NSArray * arr2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView2" owner:nil options:nil];
NSArray * arr3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView3" owner:nil options:nil];
UIView * v1 = [arr1 objectAtIndex:0];
UIView * v2 = [arr2 objectAtIndex:0];
UIView * v3 = [arr3 objectAtIndex:0];

// now you have your 3 views, do what you want with them:
v1.center = CGPointMake(100,100);
[self.view addSubview:v1];
v2.center = CGPointMake(100,200);
[self.view addSubview:v2];
v3.center = CGPointMake(100,300);
[self.view addSubview:v3];
```

Answer (score 0):

that means your first view controller's  contains two view which are from secontroller.view and thirdviewcontroller.view now third is taking press gesture but second is not taking press gesture.

please take two view on the firstviewcontroller.view
and do it like that

```
firstviewcontroller.secondVW=[[Secondviewcontroller alloc]init].view;
    firstviewcontroller.thirdVW=[[Thirdviewcontroller alloc]init].view;
```

in this manner both the view will take touches.